# Work MongoDb, Expo and React Native together for push notifications

Tags: mongodb, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

Currently I have a mobile application made with expo and react native and that shows daily weather data, in a graph it shows the data every hour (for example, average temperature). Weather data is taken from a database built on MongoDb. What I want now is that my application during the course of the day, when the temperature exceeds a higher value in the MongoDb database, a push notification is displayed in the mobile application (in production).

What I am thinking is to make an API (either in NodeJS or Python) that is constantly monitoring the database so that when a high value is reached, it sends an alert to the application and finally it can display the push notification. Now I have doubts because, how do I make my application keep listening in the background?

I have heard about firebase and apple push notification (since I am going to make the application on android and ios). Is there a way to not depend on these services?

I just want to know what path I can take and what tools I can use with to achieve what I propose. Monitor the MongoDb database, so that when a value is too high, it sends a push notification to the mobile application (in production).

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run jobs in Nodejs. It checks mongodb every 5 minutes etc. If you have any changes, you can sent push notification using the firebase api.